# REST calls in angular with Request hidden

Tags: angular, spring-boot, https, request

When making calls to my api from angular the data that I send to the requests can be seen in the inspect network of the browser, how is the correct way to hide this data?
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKxei.png)
As you can see in the screenshot, it is a login where I can see the username and password that I have set, how would I hide this information?

Comment: It is not a problem to see the data in the Inspector (SSL encryption is recommended). You should hash your password in the backend. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110948/password-hashing-on-frontend-or-backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide those data, you need SSL encryption to secure the communication between your client application and the server.